# How to install Git when you're not an admin?

Tags: openssl, building

i have been trying to install git for the last couple of days and i'm getting loads of errors.
I use the  debian OS.
I am not the admin of my system so i can't use the git package to install it(it's a school computer so i can't mess with it).
I have tried to make it manually from the source get on GitHub but i get the same error.

```
@Prompt/local/bin/git-master$ make
CC credential-store.o
In file included from cache.h:4:0,
from credential-store.c:1:
git-compat-util.h:214:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h:Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1830: recipe for target 'credential-store.o' failed
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

I have tried to install manually the missing shared library but i don't manage to get them install.

Anyone as an idea ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not the admin of my system so i can't use the git package to install it

But you can ask your friendly sysadmin to install it for you.

> openssl/ssl.h:Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

This error means that `libssl-dev` package is not installed either. You'll need to gather all the dependencies of `git` before you can build it from source.